# Criar array de strings de textarea usando \n como separador

Tags: javascript, html5, vue.js

Como criar um array de strings usando quebra de linha como separador `value.split("\n")`?

Ex:

```
<textarea placeholder="LISTA" type="text"> </textarea>
```

E como posso enviar um request utilizando axios para cada quebra de linha utilizando um foreach?

Tentativa falhada:

```
            <div id="app">
            <div v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">
              <b-form-textarea v-model="item.value"></b-form-textarea>
              <br/>
            </div>
          </div>
<script>
new Vue({
        return this.list.map(e => {
        return axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php?lista='+e.value.split("\n"))
        .then(function (response) {
          // handle success
          console.log(response);
        })
    });
})
</script>
```

Comment: faz o split e um for/foreach no resulta, então faz a chamada ajax dentro do loop

Comment: Wagner, acredito que sua dúvida não seja sobre vue, tente criar exemplos enxutos sem aquilo que não faz parte do problema, isto ajuda quem quer te ajudar, ok?

Answer (score 0):

Já respondeu sua própria pergunta: use o `split` para separar as linhas. O que faltou no seu código foi iterar sobre o array, com `for` ou `foreach` para, como perguntou, fazer uma chamada `ajax` para cada linha, ou cada item do array:

```js
document.getElementById("testar").addEventListener("click", teste);

function teste() {
  // usarei isso para que "e" seja o textarea
  var e = document.getElementById("lista");
  var lista = e.value.split("\n");

  lista.forEach(function(linha){ 
      console.log(linha);
      // então é só fazer a chamada ajax:
      // axios.get('http://localhost/fg/nova.php?lista=' + linha) ....
  });

}
```

```html
<textarea id="lista" placeholder="LISTA" type="text"> </textarea>
<button id="testar">Testar</button>
```